# How to create report in asp.net using Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have worked on Crystal Reporting before that but now i want to generate reports using Report Viewer. As i am new to this topic please Guide me. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basic tutorial for you

[Adding and Configuring the ReportViewer Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252104.aspx)

[Creating an ASP.NET report using Visual Studio 2010 - Part 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx)

[Creating an ASP.NET report using Visual Studio 2010 - Part 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-a-asp-net-interactive-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-3.aspx)

[Creating an ASP.NET report using Visual Studio 2010 - Part 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-a-asp-net-interactive-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-3.aspx)

[How to use the Report Viewer Control to access a Reporting Services Server](http://www.visualwebgui.com/Developers/KB/tabid/654/article/how_to_use_the_report_viewer_control_to_access_a_reporting_services_server/Default.aspx)

Comment: Hey Pranay....First thanks for help me out. Just there is little confusion about creating Dataset with Stored Procedures.As i have worked well with DataSet with Table so now wanna try this one.Can you post code for this.

Comment: @SonamMohite - check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234562/how-to-populate-listbox-through-a-parametrized-stored-procedure/10234618#10234618 here i have answer you will get info from this

Answer (score 1):

My code works to create Report for business class objects...

Creating Report using Business Class Objects & ReportViewer (ASP.NET/ C#)
1.Create Student Class

```
  public class StudentClass
  {
      public int No { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Degree { get; set; }
   }
```

2.Create Student Repository with GetStudents() function

```
public class StudentRepository : StudentClass
    {
        public List<StudentClass> studentList = new List<StudentClass>();

        public List<StudentClass> GetStudents()
        {            
            StudentClass student1 = new StudentClass();
            student1.No = 1;
            student1.Name = "Bhuvana";
            student1.Degree = "M.Tech";
            studentList.Add(student1);
            StudentClass student2 = new StudentClass();
            student2.No = 2;
            student2.Name = "Annie";
            student2.Degree = "B.Tech";
            studentList.Add(student2);
            StudentClass student3 = new StudentClass();
            student3.No = 3;
            student3.Name = "Muthu Abi";
            student3.Degree = "B.Tech";
            studentList.Add(student3);
            return studentList;
        }
    }
```

3.Using Report Wizard create “StudentReport.rdlc” and select DataSource

4.In Index.aspx add Script Manager and Report Viewer from ToolBox(Drag And Drop)

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>  
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>       
</div>
```

5.Modify Page_Load() method in code behind file

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    StudentRepository sr = new StudentRepository();
    List<StudentClass> sc = new List<StudentClass>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report/Student.rdlc");
            sc = sr.GetStudents();
            IEnumerable<StudentClass> ie;
            ie = sc.AsQueryable();
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ie);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        }

    }
}
```

6.Build And Run