# How to populate listbox through a parametrized stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, stored-procedures

I have a Winforms app and an employeeListBox, departmentComboBox and some textboxes to show employee information e.g. fNameTextbox, lNameTextBox.....

I want to populate the employeelistBox through the departmentCombobox selected value and populate the textboxes from the employeeListBox. I have this stored procedure for selection of employees of a department

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectEmployee] 
   @departID int
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   -- Insert statements for procedure here
   declare @ErrorCode int



   BEGIN TRANSACTION
      if ( @ErrorCode = 0 )
      Begin
        SELECT 
            EmpID, firstname, lastName, dateOfBirth, Gender, contactNumber, maritalStatus, 
            emailAddress, resentAddress, permanentAddress, nationality, bloodGroup, 
            qualification, Skills, Experience, joiiningdate, probation, departmentID, 
            Salary, paymentMode, active 
        FROM Employee
        WHERE departmentID = @departID

set @ErrorCode = @@error
      End

      if ( @ErrorCode = 0 )
     COMMIT TRANSACTION
      else
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

     return @ErrorCode
```

and to populate the listbox I wrote this code

```
    private void selectEmployee(int departID)
    {
        string connString = BL.dbConn.ConnStr;
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.selectEmployee";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        listBox1.ValueMember = "EmpID";
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "firstname";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

I do not know how to pass the departmentid to the stored procedure second how to populate the textboxes from the listbox dataset?

Comment: FYI: In your stored procedure, the line "*set @ErrorCode = @@error*" is in the wrong place, and will not do you any good. You should move it to immediately after your SELECT statement.

Comment: is that edited code work for you ....if you got it work dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted

Comment: +1 it is not giving that error but not populating the listbox

Comment: @buddy - its better you get know how to upvote and accepte asnwer on SO by visiting FAQ of the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for passing  departmentid you need to create sql parameter and need to attache with the sql command will do the work for you

thing you forget in you code is `da.SelectCommand = cmd;`specify the select command

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.selectEmployee", conn );
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@departID", value);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

for populating value in textboxes can you please post the code or example what you want to do than i can help you further in that

Comment: It is giving me this error"Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized."

Comment: @buddy = full source code is pasted by me in my edit have look to it

Comment: @PranayRana : The e of value is outside the parentheses. Should be cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@departID", value));

Comment: it is still not populating the listbox

Comment: @buddy - Do you call .DataBind() after setting the datasource?

Comment: @Pranay Rana it is giving me error on this code of line **listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;** there is no table

Comment: @buddy - you need to use datatable (da.Fill(dt)) instead of dataset and one more thing check that your database call is not throwing any error

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following in order to add the DepartmentId to the stored procedure:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@departID", departID));
```