# ReportViewer to run SSRS 2005 report

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have some SSRS 2005 reports running on a report server 2005. Now there is requirement to run one report with different parameters. There will be 50 of this report being generated. And it seems there will be more of this kind of request in future. So I am thinking there should be a way to use some programming to do this. I googled it a bit and saw the reportviewer but I have very limited knowledge of c#. So please guide me with as much details as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I am able to guess the requirement correctly but if you want to learn how to use reportviewer with c# my suggestion is to follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222980/how-to-create-report-in-asp-net-using-report-viewer

Comment: Thanks. These are helpful. But not the direct solution to my problem. I found there are two solutions (probably 3). 1. use rs.exe utility and script the .rss file to do the execution of reports. This is utility tool coming with SQL Server 2. use BCP utility to export the results of the  procedures called by the reports to excel file. But this can only output text or .xls files. And there will be no formatting. This again is a utility. But can be used in T-SQL. So is most easiest for me. 3. reportviewer. This needs programming in c#. But maybe most powerful. I haven't tied this out yet.