# How to display data from Sql Database in table in report viewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I already display data to a DataGridView in my form with these codes, now I want to display that in a report viewer. How can I do this ?

```
//Fill DataGridView
try
{
    MyDB db = new MyDB();//my connection string
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM innoviceitem WHERE id='{0}'";
    sql = string.Format(sql, id);//id is a public string that its value has been set
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, db.MyConn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    datagridview1.DataSource = bs;
}
catch (Exception err) { MessageBox.Show(err.Message); }
```

Comment: You need to create a report. See the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222980/how-to-create-report-in-asp-net-using-report-viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find useful information in following link

http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/13169999-ef3b-496c-b502-caef973c3bb2/?Using%20ReportViewer%20in%20WinForms%20C